# Почему изменение стейта не ререндерит react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

Проблема в том,что при выполнении фильтрации, когда я заполняю оба инпута-селекта, то есть фильтрую сразу по двум параметрам,стейт с отфильтованным массивом появляется с запозданием, и фильтрует по прошлым параметрам. **Как можно исправить такое поведение? В чём может заключаться причина?**
Я делаю фильтрацию в таблице,с помощью инпута-селекта. На каждый инпут-селект повешен onChange:
 `<Form.Control as={'select'} name={'manager'} onChange={this.handleChangeManagerFilter}>`
`handleChangeManagerFilter` непосредственно выполняет фильтрацию, в зависимости от того, инпут с каким именем ему приходит. Также он меняет стейт:помещает в него отфильрованный массив, и boolean-флаг который показывает что массив был отфильтрован.[[image: фильтрация по двум параметрам][1]]

Comment: Возможно, причина в том, что в state передается тот же массив, а не новый, поэтому не происходит ререндеринг. Можете попробовать передавать в функцию, изменяющую state, массив вида [...array], а не просто array. А изменение state происходит через хук `useState` или через `setState`?

Comment: Нет, в стейт определённо передаётся новый массив.Я попробовал передать [...array] это не помогло:стейт меняется только на следующий рендер, то есть всегда с запозданием.Изменение state происходит через ```setState```.Мне кажется,причина в том, что setState асинхронна. В документации по реакту рекомендуют передавать функцию, а не объект. Но мне это не подходит, так как меня не интересует предыдущее состояние, ну и к тому же это не сработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло следующее:
я стал фильтровать массив,который должен попасть в стейт, не в функции,которая потом вызывает функцию которая уже вызывает `setState`, а  ***внутри функции,которая непосредственно вызывает `setState`***. И ***в сам `setState` я стал передовать функцию, а не объект,что позволило использовать в фильтрации корректные значения `this.state`***,на которых эта фильтрация основанна : `prevState.manager` и `prevState.managerSupportForCanc`

То есть те,кто столкнётся с такой проблемой должны знать: В настоящее время `setState` работает асинхронно внутри обработчиков событий.
Более подробно читайте в документации по react "Состояние компонента"

````
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            const filtCancClients = this.props.canceledClients.filter(client => {
                if (client.ownerManager && client.ownerManager.id && client.ownerSupportManagerFirst && client.ownerSupportManagerFirst.id) {
                    const managerId = client.ownerManager.id
                    const managerSupId = client.ownerSupportManagerFirst.id
                    // console.log(`${managerId}===${this.state.manager},${managerSupId}===${this.state.managerSupportForCanc}`)
                    return managerId === prevState.manager && managerSupId === prevState.managerSupportForCanc
                }
            })
            return {[name]: filtCancClients}
        })
    }```
````